# FOS User Bundle, login on many mails

Tags: symfony, authorization, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOS User Bundle.
Now I created a table with mails for my users, they are able to add as many mails as they want. Now I'm thinking about letting them login on all of this mails kept in this table. Any tips for the best way to do? Should I only change some things in FOS or just create my own login form?

Passwords of course are still in table with users. So I have to somehow check if email is my table with mails and when it's found I have to check match password with the password from the users table (each mail is related to user, by Id of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only one email can be used to login. However you could provide a way to let the user choose one of his emails he wants to login with.

Another option of course is to override the login listeners of symfony2s security component. E.g. https://gist.github.com/smottt/1075753

```
class LoginListener
{
    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext */
    private $securityContext;

    /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
    private $em;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param SecurityContext $securityContext
     * @param Doctrine        $doctrine
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, Doctrine $doctrine)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->em              = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * Do the magic.
     * 
     * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {

    }
}
```